# Less-than OR Less-than-equal with one symbol

Tags: amsmath, stacking-symbols

I want to write a less-than-equal sign with a brace around the equal sign. Something like this, but in "nice" (at the moment, it doesn't really look as expected):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a \overset{<}{(-)} b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

That should mean something like "a is less-than-equal (less-than) b".

Is there a symbol for this or is it possible to create such a symbol?

**Edit**: To give an example where this is useful is something like this definition (to keep things short):

- If a is larger than (or equal to) b, we write: a >(=) b.

This is shorter than writing out both possiblies explicitly:

- If a is larger than b, we write: a > b.
- If a is larger than or equal to b, we write: a >= b.

Comment: Why not just `\mathrel{({\leq})}`? It's not exactly clear what `a is less-than-equal (less-than) b` would mean, because one is included in the other.

Comment: What is it useful for? < implies  ≤.

Comment: @Bernard I added an example.

Comment: I still do not see why you don't want a simple `\leq`, which means exactly what's in your title.

Comment: You can load package `amssymb` (i.e., `\usepackage{amssymb}`) and write `a \leqslant b`

Comment: @Bernard It doesn't mean the same, as the example definition shows. The title is too short to explain that in the required detail, thats why it might not perfectly reflect that. If you have an idea of a better title, I will change it.

Comment: @user94293 But thats exactly the same symbol, just that the line is not straight. I want to reflect the brace from the wording within the symbol itself.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to confuse your readers; just state the two definitions for the two symbols.

Comment: @egreg I dont really think its confusing if the symbol itself was defined and explained beforehand - just like its the case for any other symbol. If you have 8 such symbols, something like this can avoid lots of "boilerplate" definitions (8 instead of 16, still a lot but at least only the half).

Comment: @SampleTime There are other devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really difficult to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\geqp}{%
  \mathrel{\raisebox{-0.5ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle($}}%
  \geq
  \mathrel{\raisebox{-0.5ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle)$}}%
}

\begin{document}

If $a$ is larger than (or equal to) $b$, we write $a\geqp b$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However you are assigning a symbol to the obscure concept of

> being larger than (or equal to)

rather than explaining the usage of *two* symbols.

Don't do it: I'm ready to bet that your readers will not understand what you mean. Saving a few words at the expense of clarity is not worth the pain. Consider that you will be using the symbol just once.

> If *a* is larger than *b*, we write *a* > *b*. We write *a* ≥ *b* to mean that *a* > *b* or *a* = *b*.

Comment: Nice, thank you. You are probably right that it might not be a good idea after all, but its nice to see how it could be realized.